# How to validate the caller of my instruction in anchor?

Tags: anchor

How can I restrict who can call my program instruction in anchor? Suppose I have an instruction that let users to create and delete posts. Trivially I want to grant deletion permission only to the owner of a post (who originally have created it). How can I implement such validation for deletion?

```
#[program]
pub mod post {
    use super::*;
    pub fn create_post(ctx: Context<CreatePost>, content: String, id: u64) -> Result<()> {
        Ok(())
    }
    pub fn delete_post(ctx: Context<DeletePost>, id: u64) -> Result<()> {
        Ok(())
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct CreatePost<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub author: Signer<'info>,
    #[account()]
    pub post_pda: Account<'info, PostPDA>
}

#[derive(accounts)]
pub struct DeletePost<'info> {
    #[account]
    pub author: Signer<'info>
}

#[account]
pub struct PostPDA {
    pub id: u64,
    pub content: String
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd have to make an extra field for the owner in your `PostPDA` account and set it in the `create_post_instruction`. That would look like:

```
pub fn create_post(ctx: Context<CreatePost>, content: String, id: u64) -> Result<()> {
    ctx.accounts.post_pda.author = ctx.accounts.author.key();
    Ok(())
}


#[account]
pub struct PostPDA {
    pub id: u64,
    pub content: String,
    pub author: Pubkey,
}
```

Then, subsequent instructions can just check that the `author` is a signer for that instruction. For example:

```
#[derive(accounts)]
pub struct DeletePost<'info> {
    #[account]
    pub author: Signer<'info>,
    #[account(has_one = author)]
    pub post_pda: Account<'info, PostPDA>,
}
```

The `has_one = author` constraint checks that the `author` key is the same as the one saved in the `post_pda` account. This, in conjunction with the `Signer` constraint on author, guarantees that this instruction only completes successfully if the `post_pda` author's signature is present.

Comment: Here in `ctx.accounts.post_pda.owner = ctx.accounts.author.key();` by `owner` you mean the `author` field? Right?

Comment: Good catch. Thanks!

Comment: Do the `author` field in the `DeletePost` and `author` field in the `PostPDA` have to be the same?

Comment: Yh. That's the important part that actually establishes secure deletion! They have to be the same for the instruction to succeed. The `has_one` constraint enforces that the author account that is a signer in the `DeletePost` instruction is the same as the `PostPDA`'s author.

Comment: I mean do the field names have to be the same? Both field in both structures have to be named `author`?

Comment: Yh. This is required for the `has_one` constraint. `has_one = author` in this case desugars into `constraint = post_pda.author == author.key()`.

However, if the field is named differently in the post_pda account(say for example `owner`), then you can still make the same check with `constraint = post_pda.owner == author.key()`.